# UITableViewCell segue to detail view when I load cell from nib?

Tags: swift, interface-builder, segue

I have a `custom cell class` and a `custom nib` that contains the design for that cell. In my `storyboard` I don't see the way to connect the `tableview` as a `segue` (Like you have with prototype cells) I have there since my cell is added via `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

Is there a way of getting this segue connected so I can continue to use the storyboard to connect cell to detail view controller?

Here is my code for `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as MyTableViewCell?

    if (cell == nil) {
        tableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "MyTableViewCell", bundle: NSBundle(identifier: "com.company.InterfaceComponents")), forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as MyTableViewCell?
    }

    return cell!
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What I found out I could do, is to a add a manual segue (by dragging from controller) to the details controller (as Show segue with identifier: "showDetails"). Then I could add the following code on my table view:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("showDetails", sender: tableView)
}
```

Which would give me the functionality I wanted.

Comment: How would you do this with multiple cells?

Comment: Not sure what you mean with multiple cells, but you can use `indexPath` in the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` so see what cell it is in selected from.

Answer (score 3):

This is what I do in Swift 3:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "show", sender: tableView)
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "show" {
        var indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow
        let selectedRow = indexPath?.row
        let showVC = segue.destination as! NextViewController
       //do some pre-setting for next VC here with "showVC", "selectedRow" and other var you set in next VC
    }
}
```